# How to segment an image and display it in separate window using Matlab?

Tags: matlab, image-processing, image-segmentation

I'm working on counting the defected tablets in the given blisters. For that I need to segment the tablet blisters like the image. And then have to compare each segmented image with the original image which has been stored already in the DataBase. 
[image]

In the base paper for which I'm referring, they are telling to segment the input image and then compare.

Except segmenting I have done all the steps mentioned. How to segment a processed image? Do I need to save the processed image for this? Is there any function to get the segmented image like the above one?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: First, it's unclear how exactly the 4 images were taken. Second, it's unclear what exactly you want to achieve in Matlab (which is no paint btw). Finally: slicing a matrix is pretty easy and part of every beginners tutorial in Matlab. Please learn more Matlab.

Comment: @Trilarion I got that image after applying Entropy and then Blurring the resultant image. Then I saved the final resultant image and then separated using the paint to get the above result. But really thank you so much for helping me.

Comment: The crucial part here seems to be the separation. Unfortunately you still don't say how exactly you did it (mentioning the used program is not enough). Nobody can really help you if you don't explain the important things you did in a way that everyone can follow them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can crop an image in Matlab using [`imcrop`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imcrop.html). For displaying an image you can use either [`imshow`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/imshow.html) or [`imagesc`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/imagesc.html). You can display several images on the same figure using [`subplot`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/subplot.html):

```
img = imread( 'path/to/your/image.png' ); %// read image from disk
c1 = imcrop( img, [10 20 50 100] ); %// crop a portion of the image
c2 = imcrop( img, [70 20 50 100] ); %// crop another portion
%//displaying
figure;
subplot(1,2,1);imshow(c1,[]);title('first crop');
subplot(1,2,2);imshow(c2,[]);title('second crop');
```